# SQL Query w/ multiple name / value pairs in Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table called  `Properties` (pid, uid, pname, pvalue). The pid column is auto generated. Each uid (user id) could have multiple name value pairs stored in the pname and pvalue.

As an input I've multiple name value pairs for pname and pvalue which forms a complicated boolean expression.

For example: let's start w/ one name value pair. Say I want to retrieve all uid's whose 'favorite_color' is 'red'.

I wrote an SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM properties 
 WHERE ((pname = 'favorite_color') and (pvalue = 'red'))
```

The query soon gets complicated if I had to retrieve something like, fetch all uid's whose 'favorite_color' is 'red' or 'blue' and 'favorite_drink' is 'juice' or ' 'milk' and 'favorite_ hobby' is 'music' or 'art' etc.

I wrote an SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM properties 
 WHERE (((pname = 'favorite_color') and (pvalue = 'red')) 
    OR ((pname = 'favorite_color') and (pvalue = 'blue'))) 
   AND (((pname = 'favorite_drink') and (pvalue = 'juice')) 
    OR ((pname = 'favorite_drink') and (pvalue = 'milk'))) 
   AND (((pname = 'favorite_hobby') and (pvalue = 'music')) 
    OR ((pname = 'favorite_hobby') and (pvalue = 'art')))
```

I got the expression correct but unfortunately it fails because the evaluation is done on each row. What if I wanted to add more name value pairs to the where clause?

Questions:

1. Is it possible to write and SQL query for this?
2. The other idea I had was to fetch all the pname, pvalue pairs for each user, build a dynamic expression using an expression language and my input name value paris to evaluate it. I've apache's JEXL in mind.

Comment: Use `UNION`/`UNION ALL` (depending on needs) to separate the criteria

Comment: Are you suggesting something like this? SELECT * 
  FROM properties 
 WHERE (((pname = 'favorite_color') and (pvalue = 'red')) 
    OR ((pname = 'favorite_color') and (pvalue = 'blue'))) UNION
   SELECT * FROM properties (((pname = 'favorite_drink') and (pvalue = 'juice')) 
    OR ((pname = 'favorite_drink') and (pvalue = 'milk'))) UNION 
   SELECT * 
  FROM properties (((pname = 'favorite_hobby') and (pvalue = 'music')) 
    OR ((pname = 'favorite_hobby') and (pvalue = 'art')))

Comment: Suppose I had three rows  1, 1, favorite_color, red  2, 2, favorite_drink, juice  3, 3, favorite_hobby, music.  The above query will result in returning all the three rows / uid's. Is that right? If so that is not the desired result, am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do the ANDs you need to do as many self-joins as you have and-ed conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM Properties p1, Properties p2, Properties p3
WHERE p1.uid = p2.uid AND p1.uid = p3.uid
AND (p1.pname = 'favorite_color' AND p1.pvalue IN ('red', 'blue'))
AND (p2.pname = 'favorite_drink' AND p2.pvalue IN ('juice', 'milk'))
AND (p3.pname = 'favorite_hobby' AND p2.pvalue IN ('music', 'art'))
```

EDIT:

Another possibility is to denormalize the data, and then use `FIND_IN_SET()` or `RLIKE`:

```
SELECT uid, group_concat(concat(pname, '=', pvalue)) props
FROM Properties
GROUP BY uid
HAVING props RLIKE 'favorite_color=(red|blue)'
AND props RLIKE 'favorite_drink=(juice|milk)'
AND props RLIKE 'favorite_hobby=(music|art)'
```

Comment: It makes sense but for now I've 6 such properties (favorite_*) and it could grow more too. A cartesian product of 6 of these w/ say a 1M rows in the table would result it what? I can't even image that complexity. Should I think in the lines of restructuring my schema/table?

Comment: See my new query in the EDIT.

Comment: It looks good. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve as part of my questions (#2 point). Get the uid's, property pairs using SQL query as first half and process them in my java code which forms the second half. Didn't realize that there is an inherent rich support of functions in the SQL itself. I'll try this out a little bit more and update you. I appreciate the help again.

Comment: Not accepting was unintentional. Some of them did not have solutions. I revisited all of my questions again and accepted 3 of them. I'll make sure that I'll do the same of this question too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.*,p2.pname,p2.pvalue,p3.pname,p3.pvalue
FROM (
       (Select * 
        from Properties  
        where (pname = 'favorite_color' AND pvalue IN ('red', 'blue')) p1, 
       (Select * 
        from Properties  
        where (pname = 'favorite_drink' AND pvalue IN ('juice','milk')) p2, 
       (Select * 
        from Properties  
        where (pname = 'favorite_hobby' AND pvalue IN ('music', 'art')) p3, 
     )
WHERE p1.uid = p2.uid AND p1.uid = p3.uid
```

Comment: This sounds good but the only problem I've w/ this solution is scalability. The more properties I add the query turns out more complicated.